# How to convert data disk to OS disk in Azure using python

Tags: python, azure

I am creating a VM from a disk in azure using python. I have all the OS data in a data disk and I am creating a VM from it. I am using this commmand for creating VM from disk:

```
az vm create --resource-group RESOURCE-GRP-NAME \
       --location eastus --name VM-NAME --os-type linux \
       --attach-os-disk DISK-NAME
```

The VM gets created successfully and runs normally on the azure portal, but it fails when I try to ssh it via terminal. So I think that the data disk must be converted to an OS disk first before creating a VM from it. So how do I do that in **python**.

Comment: Please include your code in your question or did you crash into some errors?

Comment: @JayGong I used this command on CLI =>                                            **az vm create --resource-group resource-group-name --location eastus --name vm-name --os-type linux --attach-os-disk disk-name**........But there is no option for giving username and password. So while connecting to VM via ssh, it is not working.

Comment: @JayGong can you please help me to solve this user name and password issue.

Comment: You need to either set your username and password on the new os disk before you swap, or update azure's vm info to match. You can do the later using the standard [create_or_update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update) command in python. You don't need to do anything special to convert it, so this question doesn't really make sense

Comment: @MingweiSamuel Without converting it to OS disk, the VM won't spawn up. So it is required to convert it. And regarding setting the username and password, I did not find any CLI command for the same. Hence I was looking for this answer. Although, setting up username and password was/is better option, but I could not find the commands for them.